# Anyway to make html/body scroll range shorter than the page height with niceScroll

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

Is there a way to make the scrolling area height of nice scroll shorter than the page height so it starts after the nav and end before the page bottom?
I tried that  jsFiddle example ( [code page](http://jsfiddle.net/24bbLj3z/1/) , [view page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/24bbLj3z/1/show/) ) but this is not a solution for me"

```
var _nScroll = false;
if (typeof $.fn.niceScroll != 'undefined') {
    _nScroll = {
    horizrailenabled: false,
    zindex: 2,
    cursorborder: "none",
    cursorwidth: "8px",
    cursorcolor: "#515154",
    background: "#cbcdd0",
    autohidemode: false,
    railoffset: {top:'50px',left:0}
    };
    $("html").niceScroll( _nScroll );
}
$(".nicescroll-rails").css({
    'top': '70px',
    'right': '7px',
    'bottom': '50px',
    'height': $(window).height() - 100
});
```

Comment: apply it to a different element instead of `html` tag

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl That will require a huge change in the app pages and structure .. might be a final solution since it's only a design issue. thanks